# How to remove/hide text at the very top of the page

Tags: php, postgresql

**Problem**

I would like to know how I would make the text at the top of the screen not show when connecting or searching the database. Below is a screenshot of what I am talking about.

[image: Screenshot of webpage]

Is it possible for it to not appear at all? Below is the code that connects to the database, as well as the code for the form below.

**Code**

The code to connect to the database:

```
<?php       
    // Connecting, selecting database
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=***** port=*****
    dbname=***** user=***** password=*****")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    //collect
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        // $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"."".$searchq);

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = "SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code LIKE '%$searchq%'";
    $ret = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
   if(!$ret){
      echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
      exit;
   } 
   $output = '';
   while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret)){
            $code = $row['code'];
            print_r($row);
            $name = $row['name'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $vegan = $row['vegan'];

            $output .= '<div> '.vegan.' ';
   }
}
   echo "Operation done successfully\n";
   pg_close($dbconn);

?>
```

The code for the form:

```
<div id="tablebox">
            <!-- Search bar -->
            <p>Is It Vegan?</p>
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="searchEnumbers.php">
                <input name="search" type="text" size="30" maxlength="5" />
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>

            <?php
                print("$output");
            ?>
        </div>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove these two lines from your code

```
print_r($row);

.....

echo "Operation done successfully\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, Changes are noted via **php comment (//)**

```
<?php       
    // Connecting, selecting database
    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=***** port=*****
    dbname=***** user=***** password=*****")
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

    //collect
    if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        // $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i"."".$searchq);

    // Performing SQL query
    $query = "SELECT vegan FROM enumbers WHERE code LIKE '%$searchq%'";
    $ret = pg_query($dbconn, $query);
   if(!$ret){
      echo pg_last_error($dbconn);
      exit;
   } 
   $output = '';
   while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($ret)){
            $code = $row['code'];
            //Commented 1
            //print_r($row);
            $name = $row['name'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $vegan = $row['vegan'];

            $output .= '<div> '.vegan.' ';
   }
}
   //Commented 2
   //echo "Operation done successfully\n";
   pg_close($dbconn);

?>
```